# Send and Receive with ESP8266 and arduino

Tags: esp8266

Hi i would like to implement a sensor and control system for my home. Basically, i would like to send and receive data to my arduino uno using esp8266. I am able program the esp8266 using at commands to send http request to my server. How can i make my server send commands to my arduino uno using esp8266?

Comment: Do you want your "server" to send instructions direct to the esp8266 (esp8266 is a server), or do you want your esp8266 to connect to the server, send a request, then the server returns commands as a response (esp8266 is a client)?

Comment: Im not using the esp8266 alone, but using the esp8266 chip as a way for me to connect to the internet. I would like the esp8266 to be able to initiate a command to the server and be able to receive commands at any time without sending a command to get the response.

Comment: Then you need your esp to run as both a client and server. Open a listening socket and respond to the requests that come in.

Comment: Is there a library for socket for esp8266?

Comment: No idea. I always program my ESPs directly in C.